# About None in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I am a beginner to Ocaml. I am trying to write some code about normal order reduction, and is confused by some syntax. The following is some truncated code to isolate my error.

```
type expr =
| Var of char
| Num of int
| Lambda of expr
| Apply of expr * expr

let rec substitute f id e = match f with
| Num(i) -> if id == i then e else f
| _ -> f

let rec beta_lor e = match e with
| Apply(Lambda(f), e2) -> substitute f 1 e2
| Apply(e1,e2) -> beta_lor e1
| Lambda e1 -> beta_lor e1
| _ -> None
```

In a file of .mli I claim the beta_lor shall be of type:
val beta_lor: expr -> expr option

Now when I compile this file it report error about the line the "None" I used in beta_lor:
Error: This expression has type 'a option
       but an expression was expected of type expr

I understand that ocaml compiler tries to do type inference, and it expects me to output an expression, rather than 'a option, but I have claimed that beta_lor may output option? I am somewhat confused, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `substitute` *doesn't* return `expr option`. It just returns `expr`. Maybe what you want is for `beta_lor` to return `Some (substitute f 1 e2)` for that case.

**Edit**

For what it's worth, your descriptions seem to be based on the idea that an option type is like a pointer type in a mainstream language, either an interesting pointer or NULL. It's more enlightening (in my opinion) to focus on the fact that there are exactly two cases: `Some` *expr* and `None`. You need to wrap and unwrap these two cases explicitly in OCaml, which (again, in my opinion) is vastly better than treating NULL as a legal pointer value. We see around us every day the downside of the mainstream model (sorry for editorializing).

Comment: ok, thanks now it compiles. But I am confused how ocaml compiler works for type inference in this case, is it the case that it scans the cases of match and try to deduce the output type shall be either expr (what output by substitute) or None? Or, it just looks at the first case, and deduce the output shall be expr?

Comment: It looks at *all* of them and makes sure they're the same (unifying types as necessary). In my opinion, the most confusing thing about it is the error message! The difference between the "expected" and "seen" types is not particularly well defined. It's usually clearer (to me) just to think of it as a general kind of type conflict (different types where they should be the same).

Comment: OK, this makes sense, so it unifies "expr option" type with " 'a option" type, if I write Some (substitute f 1 e2). This implies that it fails to unify "expr" and " 'a option ", but should this case be naturally "seen" to be " expr option"? Do I miss anything?

Comment: I think you have it, except I don't understand "naturally". Everything is based on the code, you don't have to introduce external notions of naturalness. But I think you have it.